# How can I read all target URLs in IdHTTPProxyServer

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-xe4

How can I read all the full target URL's in IdHTTPProxyServer? The following code only works HTTP urls. For HTTPS it will only return `Server:443` instead of a full URL.

```
procedure TManager.OnHTTPBeforeCommand(AContext: TIdHTTPProxyServerContext);
var
  URL:String;
begin
  URL := AContext.Target;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS proxying utilizes the HTTP `CONNECT` verb, which does not connect to a URL, only a host:port.  The web client CONNECTs to the target server first to establish a base connection, then establishes an SSL session with that server before then sending the actual HTTP request to it.  Since the request is encrypted, there is no way for `TIdHTTPProxyServer` to capture the full HTTPS URL.

Comment: Can I use TIdMappedPortTCP + TIdHttp instead?

Comment: The HTTPS url is part of the HTTP request data that is not transmitted until after the connection has been encrypted. Regardless of what kind of proxy you use, the only way to capture the unencypted data is with a Man-In-The-Middle attack.

Comment: And how can that be done? I am looking to monitor HTTPS requests from TWebbrowser. And I haven't been able to find a solution for this, yet.

Comment: Fiddler uses MITM techniques (Fiddler's own website says so) to intercept an SSL handshake sent through a `CONNECT` connection so a web client ends up creating an SSL session with Fiddler itself, and then Fiddler creates a separate SSL session with the target server. Fiddler can then decrypt the web client's data and re-encrypt it when forwarding to the target server, and vice versa. *Can* you do that with `TIdHTTPProxyServer`? *Probably*, with a bit of extra work. You have to enable and activate SSL on both ends of the Context, deal with certificates, etc.

Comment: That would mean using `makecert.exe` ? So I only need to create a fake certificate and thats pretty much it.

Comment: It is a little more complex than that. For instance, if the client attempts to validate the fake certificate, it will fail since it does not belong to the target server that the client is trying to reach. The whole point of certificates is to prevent MITM attacks. To get around that, Fiddler generates its own root CA certificate to sign other certificates it gives to clients. That root CA certificate has to be trusted by clients, usually by installing it onto the client machine in whatever certificate store the client uses.

Comment: I've done this. I simply create a wildcard certificate for each domain on the fly, using a self-signed CA cert. It's easy to install the root cert for IE, but it does require user interaction.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Can you elaborate on that a bit how it works in detail ? Thanks! :)